# Cordova App is loading before styles are loaded

Tags: android, cordova, onsen-ui

Im creating a cordova app using onsenui. Have only android platform.

It loads before styles are loaded. I can see all the html file without styles for a couple of seconds. 
Can i get a solution?

Comment: just use DeviceReady event

Comment: how to add that ? can i get a code

Comment: please note that this event will be called only once when all your stylesheets are loaded successfully. I think you can use some kind of overlay (splash) to hide your first page until this callback is called. https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/cordova/events/events.deviceready.html